# Cannot modify an array passed to a function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define liczbaStudentow 20  //stala liczba studentow
#define liczbaPrzedmiotow 5 //stala liczba przedmiotow
#define maksymalnaDlugosc 30
#define liczbaImionINazwisk 50

typedef struct {
    char imie[40];
    char nazwisko[40];
    float oceny[liczbaPrzedmiotow];
} Student;

int losujProporcje() {
    int proporcja = rand() % liczbaStudentow;
    return proporcja;
}

void losowanieImionINazwisk(int tablicaTymczasowa[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < liczbaImionINazwisk; i++) {
        //przypisanie wartosci domyslnych do tablicy
        tablicaTymczasowa[i] = i;
    }

    int zmiennaLosowaTymczasowa = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < liczbaImionINazwisk; i++) {
        zmiennaLosowaTymczasowa = rand() % liczbaImionINazwisk;
        tablicaTymczasowa[i] = tablicaTymczasowa[zmiennaLosowaTymczasowa];
    }
}
    
void wygenerowanieStudentow(int proporcja, Student strukturaStudentow[],
                            char imionaMeskie[], char nazwiskaMeskie[],
                            char imionaZenskie[], char nazwiskaZenskie[]) {
    int zmiennaLosowaUniwersalna;
    int tablicaTymczasowa[liczbaImionINazwisk];
    losowanieImionINazwisk(tablicaTymczasowa);

    for (int i = 0; i < proporcja; i++) {
        strcpy(strukturaStudentow[i].imie,
               &imionaMeskie[tablicaTymczasowa[i]]);
    
        strcpy(strukturaStudentow[i].nazwisko,
               &nazwiskaMeskie[tablicaTymczasowa[i]]);
    
        for (int j = 0; j < liczbaPrzedmiotow; j++) {
            strukturaStudentow[i].oceny[j] = (float)(rand() % 5 + 2);
        }
    }
    for (int i = proporcja; i < (liczbaStudentow - proporcja); i++) {
        strcpy(strukturaStudentow[i].imie,
               &imionaZenskie[tablicaTymczasowa[i]]);
    
        strcpy(strukturaStudentow[i].nazwisko,
               &nazwiskaZenskie[tablicaTymczasowa[i]]);
    
        for (int j = 0; j < liczbaPrzedmiotow; j++) {
            strukturaStudentow[i].oceny[j] = (float)(rand() % 5 + 2);
        }
    }
}

void printStudentsWithGrades(Student strukturaStudentow[], char przedmioty[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < liczbaStudentow; i++) {
        printf("Imie i nazwisko: %s %s, Oceny z przedmiotow: ",
               strukturaStudentow[i].imie, strukturaStudentow[i].nazwisko);
        for (int j = 0; j < liczbaPrzedmiotow; j++) {            
            printf("%s: %f", przedmioty[j], strukturaStudentow[i].oceny[j]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    char imionaMeskie[50][maksymalnaDlugosc] = {
        "Adam", "Aleksander", "Andrzej", "Antoni", "Bartłomiej",
        "Bogdan", "Cezary", "Damian", "Dariusz", "Dawid", "Edward",
        "Fabian", "Feliks", "Filip", "Franciszek", "Grzegorz",
        "Henryk", "Igor", "Jacek", "Jan", "Józef", "Kamil", "Karol",
        "Lech", "Lesław", "Marek", "Mariusz", "Mateusz", "Michał",
        "Piotr", "Rafał", "Robert", "Sebastian", "Sławomir",
        "Stanisław", "Tomasz", "Wojciech", "Zbigniew", "Zdzisław",
        "Adrian", "Arkadiusz", "Bartosz", "Damian", "Daniel",
        "Dariusz", "Dominik", "Fabian", "Grzegorz", "Jakub",
        "Kamil"
    };
    char nazwiskaMeskie[50][maksymalnaDlugosc] = {
        "Kowalski", "Mazur", "Kowalczyk", "Wojciechowski",
        "Kamiński", "Kowalewski", "Zieliński", "Szymański",
        "Woźniak", "Dąbrowski", "Kozłowski", "Jankowski",
        "Wojciechowski", "Kwiatkowski", "Kaczmarek", "Malinowski",
        "Piotrowski", "Grabowski", "Nowakowski", "Pawłowski",
        "Michalski", "Adamczyk", "Dudek", "Zając", "Wieczorek",
        "Jabłoński", "Król", "Majewski", "Olszewski", "Jaworski",
        "Wróbel", "Makowski", "Kaczmarczyk", "Domański", "Zalewski",
        "Jakubowski", "Jasiński", "Zawadzki", "Sadowski", "Bąk",
        "Chmielewski", "Włodarczyk", "Borkowski", "Czarnecki",
        "Sawicki", "Sokolowski", "Urbanski", "Kubiak", "Maciejewski",
        "Szewczyk"
    };
    char imionaZenskie[50][maksymalnaDlugosc] = {
        "Anna", "Maria", "Katarzyna", "Agnieszka", "Ewa",
        "Małgorzata", "Joanna", "Krystyna", "Barbara", "Elżbieta",
        "Danuta", "Halina", "Helena", "Irena", "Jadwiga", "Janina",
        "Kazimiera", "Magdalena", "Teresa", "Zofia", "Dorota",
        "Aleksandra", "Bożena", "Cecylia", "Ewelina", "Gabriela",
        "Iwona", "Julia", "Karolina", "Lidia", "Liliana", "Lucyna",
        "Marianna", "Monika", "Renata", "Sandra", "Stanisława",
        "Urszula", "Weronika", "Zuzanna", "Beata", "Jolanta",
        "Stanisława", "Alicja", "Amelia", "Kamila", "Kinga", "Maja",
        "Natalia", "Paulina"
    };
    char nazwiskaZenskie[50][maksymalnaDlugosc] = {
        "Nowak", "Kowalska", "Wiśniewska", "Wójcik", "Kowalczyk",
        "Kamińska", "Lewandowska", "Dąbrowska", "Zielińska",
        "Szymańska", "Woźniak", "Kozłowska", "Jankowska", "Mazur",
        "Wojciechowska", "Kwiatkowska", "Krawczyk", "Kaczmarek",
        "Piotrowska", "Grabowska", "Zając", "Pawłowska", "Nowacka",
        "Adamczyk", "Tyszkiewicz", "Stępień", "Olszewska", 
        "Jabłońska", "Chmielewska", "Włodarczyk", "Borkowska",
        "Czarnecka", "Sobczak", "Krupa", "Maciejewska", "Sikora",
        "Mróz", "Dudek", "Kot", "Stasiak", "Baran", "Rutkowska",
        "Michalska", "Sawicka", "Sadowska", "Wróblewska", "Walczak",
        "Sosnowska", "Kacprzak", "Kempowinska"
    };
    char przedmioty[5][maksymalnaDlugosc] = {
        "Matematyka 1:", "Matematyka 2:", "J. angielski:", 
        "Informatyka", "Etyka Zawodowa"
    };
    
    Student strukturaStudentow[20]; //zainicjowanie listy struktur o typie Student
    
    int proporcja = losujProporcje();

    wygenerowanieStudentow(proporcja, strukturaStudentow, imionaMeskie, 
                           nazwiskaMeskie, imionaZenskie, nazwiskaZenskie);
    
    printStudentsWithGrades(strukturaStudentow, przedmioty);
    
    return 0;
}
```

My task it to create a data base for students. I created arrays with mens' and womens' names, so that the program can randomly assign names and surnames to 20 "created" people.

What I am trying to achieve in `losowanieImionINazwisk` is to pass a array and modify it in the `wygeneroanieStudentow` method. The thing is, the program does not work, even after I have tried passing by pointer and without it.

Still, I cannot, the program does not start. Can someone help?

I tried passing by pointer, still cannot solve the issue.

Comment: There are very many warnings and errors. First off, `void losowanieImionINazwisk(int *tablicaTymczasowa[])` needs an array of pointers, not an array of `int`.

Comment: Pay attention to the warnings your compiler is emitting.  If it's not emitting any, then turn up the warning level or get a better compiler.

Comment: In the `losowanieImionINazwisk` function, the variable `tablicaTymczasowa` is an array of *pointers* to `int`. So assigning plain `int` values to it doesn't make any sense. Also, calling `losowanieImionINazwisk` as you do doesn't make sense either. To solve the proelbmes, change the `tablicaTymczasowa` argument to plain `int *tablicaTymczasowa`, and the call to `losowanieImionINazwisk(tablicaTymczasowa)`

Comment: the idea is to pass an array to function and modify it's elements

Comment: But now you're passing a *pointer* to the array, which will have the type `int (*)[liczbaImionINazwisk]`. That type is not the same as `int **` which your current argument is. And you should not use the pointer-to operator `&` in the call, remember that array decays to pointers to their first element automatically. So Using plain `tablicaTymczasowa` in the call is the same as `&tablicaTymczasowa[0]`, which have the type `int *`. Which is the type your function-argument should be.

Comment: You should provide a [mre], use English, fix all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example show a call to `losowanieImionINazwisk()` with an uninitalized array input showing it working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define liczbaImionINazwisk 50

void losowanieImionINazwisk(int *tablicaTymczasowa) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < liczbaImionINazwisk; i++)
        tablicaTymczasowa[i] = i;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < liczbaImionINazwisk; i++)
        tablicaTymczasowa[i] = tablicaTymczasowa[rand()% liczbaImionINazwisk];
}

int main() {
    int tablicaTymczasowa[liczbaImionINazwisk];
    losowanieImionINazwisk(tablicaTymczasowa);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < liczbaImionINazwisk; i++)
        printf("%d ", tablicaTymczasowa[i]);
}
```

and the output is:

```
33 36 27 15 43 35 36 42 49 21 12 27 40 21 21 26 40 26 22 36 27 22 26 29 32 30 40 29 26 35 35 27 26 49 36 26 43 36 27 42 35 29 22 36 36 36 48 32 26 27
```